# What does Citrix's definition of Load Bias mean?

Tags: citrix, load-balancing

I'm having trouble understanding the definition. It can be found [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX103653&searchID=35054236). Small section:

> The Load Bias also called the Protocol Mask, is retained in the memory resident database referred to as the dynamic store on the data collector. The dynamic store uses the Load Bias value to inflate the load for the server during the client resolution phase until the true load value is received.
>
> If a server is least loaded by a load value of 1000, a Load Bias of 100 decimal allows 10 connections to be resolved to that server before subsequent connections are balanced to the other servers. This is a temporary condition until the server sends the load update to the local data collector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum load assignment and preference at initial client connect/access until the "true" load is determined.

Comment: so is it just an upper bound on "true" load? Like a load will first be assumed to be 100, then it's later updated to its true value of 40? So if that were true for all connections, then 10 would connect, and the server would think its full, but after they all updated you'd have room for 6 more initial connections, etc?

Comment: Initial assumption until the true load is determined - where to "park" initial sessions as all session initiations may not follow-through to become actual sessions (e.g. DoS attacks).